# Find Months gone from a specific date

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am able to find difference between two dates in months, But my exact requirement is how many months gone from a specific date.

suppose , user signups on 2nd July 2016 or 31st July 2016, so 1st August it should return me as - 2nd month i.e July and August.
And if user signs up on 2nd August 2016 and today is 18th August 2016 , it should return me 1.

Note that we also want to consider the year count, i.e if year changes it should give me count as 13 , 14 etc.

I have tried many ways to find it out all fails

Answer (score 0):

This should be enough :

```
date2.getMonth() - date1.getMonth() + (date2.getYear() - date1.getYear())*12 + 1
```

Examples :

```
var date1= new Date("2016-07-02");
var date2= new Date("2016-08-01");
console.log(date2.getMonth() - date1.getMonth() + (date2.getYear() - date1.getYear())*12 + 1);
> 2

var date1= new Date("2016-08-02");
var date2= new Date("2016-08-18");
console.log(date2.getMonth() - date1.getMonth() + (date2.getYear() - date1.getYear())*12 + 1);
> 1

var date1= new Date("2015-08-02");
var date2= new Date("2016-08-18");
console.log(date2.getMonth() - date1.getMonth() + (date2.getYear() - date1.getYear())*12 + 1);
> 13
```